# How do I cross compile QT application from ubuntu to windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, ubuntu, cross-compiling

First I tried installing mingw and adding it to Qt creator's build kits, but I couldn't figure out how, and all the instructions I found on line just said it's easy without saying what to do.

Next I tried using mxe, and I just get linker errors, mostly to do with zlib and freetype, but the linker flags for both are there, and it doesn't say it can't find the libraries.

And while I can find similar errors in several stack overflow questions, none of them have answers.  So I'm at a loss, how do I do this?

Comment: MXE usually works fine. What are the errors? Have you verified that zlib and freetype are built by MXE?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attempting to get cross-compiling working (which can be difficult, error prone and prone to failure when something changes), you should rather set up a build environment on all your target platforms (virtual machines work well for this) and then compile and package your product natively.

I know that this does not answer your question "as such", but it answers the question you *should* have asked.
Just don't bother with cross-compilation, it's too much painful work. Just use a VM and get on with productive work :)

Comment: Agree. Crosscompilation targets weak platforms. But for a Raspberry Pi, native compilation is already a serious option.

Comment: I don't have a windows license, so I can't set up the target platform.

Comment: *If* you ask me; buying a Windows license is going to be *far* cheaper than the time you'll spend on getting cross-compilation working.

Comment: . . . and cross-compiling is necessary for targeting many embedded devices, so it may be worth the effort.